# Is it OK to keep TreeNode reference?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

By default Visual Studio doesn't keep references on TreeNodes at class level when they are created in designer mode in TreeViews.

I found that for some nodes that I frequently access, it would be much easier to have reference to them, than to access them by their Name property, as it is easier to type.

However, I wonder if this approach has some downsides? In my case, those TreeNodes are kept alive as long as application is running anyway, so my guess is that keeping such reference could not harm, but just checking, it is interesting that I couldn't find any similar question or text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well technically it is keeping a reference to each Node or you wouldn't be able to access them at all and they would be garbage collected. If you're planning on calling a Node more than the others I suppose it would be okay to create another reference. You would then have 2 references to that Node though.

Comment: Yes, but having one more reference is not expensive in terms of resources, right? Actually, I could get rid of the Name string, so I think that it would be at least even...

Comment: Well, more expensive than having 1 I guess. A reference is really just a pointer to that objects location in memory, not a hard-copy of it. As long as you have at least one reference of it. If you want to create another reference for readability ease, which seems to be your case (Am I right?) then go for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can keep the references without any problem in your case.
Remember to update the references as soon as they become obsolete.